# How to use cellTooltip with cellTemplate in angular ui grid

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-grid

i am using angular ui grid, there is one column which is getting html string as input, so to display the column value i am using ng-bind-html in cellTemplate(which works fine to display plain inner text), but cellTooltip doesn't work for tooltip(it doesn't), if i use title="{{row.entity.htmlfield}}" in cellTemplate then it shows html string but i need the plain text, how can i achieve this?

what i am using :

```
$scope.datagrid={
 colDefs=[
        {
           field:'htmlfield',
           cellTemplate:'<div title="{{row.entity.htmlfield}}" ng-bind-html="{{row.entity.htmlfield}}"></div>',//html field is expecting html content
           cellTooltip:function(row,col){
           return row.entity.htmlfield //it doesn't work with cellTemplate//
}
        }
      ]
```

}

Comment: field:'htmlfield', cellTemplate:'<div title="{{row.entity.htmlfield}}">{{row.entity.htmlfield}}</div>',

Answer (score 3):

**Solution 1:**
Remove **`cellTooltip`** when you use `cellTemplate`
You can use a filter like

```
app.filter('trusted', function ($sce) {
  return function (value) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(value);
  }
});
```

And inside `cellTemplate` use -

```
title="{{row.entity.htmlfield | trusted}}"
```

**Solution 2:**

You can create a filter on above lines and use it in `cellFilter`
Tooltips respect the cellFilter, so if you define a cellFilter it will also be used in the tooltip.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks mate ! this solution surely does work, with my solution the built-in filtering of ui-grid was not working correctly but with filter it does, but somehow $sce.trustAsHtml doesnt work for me i had tried this earlier also, in filter i had to use regular expression to convert the html to plain text and then return it.

Comment: @user2889674 - good to know that you found a working solution. please post it as an answer and accept it so that it is useful for other users.

Answer (score 2):

We can use cellTemplate and cellTooltip like below, for example,

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: [
      { name: 'name', cellTemplate:"<div class='ui-grid-cell-contents'  title='{{grid.appScope.customTooltip(row,col,COL_FIELD)}}'>{{COL_FIELD CUSTOM_FILTERS}}</div>"
      }
]

$scope.customTooltip = function (row,col,value) {
    console.log(row);
    console.log(col);
    return value;
  }
```

I have created function for cellTooltip and passed it into title tag, and its working fine. https://plnkr.co/edit/Dcpwy5opZ9BwC8YdWf3H?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

So simple
just remove `cellTooltip` and add `title` tag in the cellTemplate div.

```
{
   field:'htmlfield',
   cellTemplate:'<div title="{{row.entity.htmlfield}}">{{row.entity.htmlfield}}</div>',
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I achieved the goal using a custom directive the code for the directive is like

```
$scope.datagrid={
  colDefs=[
            {
               field:'htmlfield',
               cellTemplate:'<tool-tip text="{{row.entity.htmlfield}}"></tool-tip>',//html field is expecting html content, no need to use cellTooltip as it doesn't work//
            }
          ]
}
//create a custom directive to give required feel to your field template//
angular.module('app').directive('tooTip',function(){
          var linkFunction=function(scope,element,attributes){
                  scope.text=String(attributes['text']).replace('/<[^>]+>/gm', ''); 
          };
return{
    restrict:'E',
    template:'<div title="{{text}}">{{text}}</div>',
    link:linkFunction,
    scope:{}

};
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Need to change like this

```
cellTemplate:'<div title="{{row.entity.htmlfield}}">{{row.entity.htmlfield}}</div>'
```

Answer (score 0):

### Original cellTemplate from ui-grid source:

```
"<div class=\"ui-grid-cell-contents\" title=\"TOOLTIP\">{{COL_FIELD CUSTOM_FILTERS}}</div>"
```

In this template TOOLTIP and COL_FIELD and CUSTOM_FILTERS are ui-grid macro-s.

I define cellTemplate (only icon), and use cellTooltip (with fields error messages), and to work freely:

```
columnDefs: [
{
...
cellTemplate: '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-alert" title="TOOLTIP"></span>',
cellTooltip: function( row, col ) {
                        return ...;
             }
...
}
]
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking here. If you could add more details and a specific question it would help you garner useful answers.